# Lightbox2 adds an extra image at the end of full screen image set

Tags: html, jquery, css, lightbox2

I've just noticed that Lightbox2 (*https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2*) is duplicating or adding extra images at the end of the full screen version of the image, everything else works fine. When viewing I click on the next image arrow for the next image and when I reach the last one (*image_5.jpg*) there shouldn't be any more "next" button/option, but there is and if I click it, it shows once again the last image.

```
<div class="galleryContainer">
  <div class="gallery_image">
    <a class="example-image-link" href="./images/studio/image_1.jpg" data-lightbox="studio-set"><img class="studio-image" src="./images/studio/image_1.jpg" alt=""/>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="./images/studio/image_2.jpg" data-lightbox="studio-set"><img class="studio-image" src="./images/studio/image_2.jpg" alt=""/>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="./images/studio/image_3.jpg" data-lightbox="studio-set"><img class="studio-image" src="./images/studio/image_3.jpg" alt=""/>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="./images/studio/image_4.jpg" data-lightbox="studio-set"><img class="studio-image" src="./images/studio/image_4.jpg" alt=""/>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="./images/studio/image_5.jpg" data-lightbox="studio-set"><img class="studio-image" src="./images/studio/image_5.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>

<script src="./scripts/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```